# Will making my question community wiki kill the incentive to post answers for it?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

Most of the time, when I post questions, I try to remind myself that what I'm looking for is answers, not empty rep.  As such, I'm in favor of turning the things that I post into community wiki's.  But it seems like if people don't get rep for answering my question, then it's -less- likely it'll be responded to, which makes a really good reason for not making it CW.

Made this CW just for irony's sake.

**Edit:** Or am I missing something, and CW on a question doesn't cause CW on answers?

Comment: You made this a wiki? You sure about that?

Comment: Huh, guess not.  Is now.  :p  Irony fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Will making my question community wiki kill the incentive to post answers for it?**

Yes.  Depending on the question it may not matter, though - popular questions may get attention just because people want to chime in on the topic.

But for regular "can be objectively answered" questions, CW will cause some users to shy away - it's hard enough to get rep as it is, without spending time on questions that are guaranteed to give no rep.

**Does CW on a question cause CW on answers?**

It does for any answers made after the question was made CW.  So if you start a question CW, then every answer is CW.  If you change to CW an hour after you post it, any *new* answers are CW, but older answers aren't (unless the answer author chose CW when they posted their answer).

Comment: That is complex indeed.  I assumed that rep before CW was kept, and rep after CW is non-existent (I'm assuming that even answers that weren't originally CW don't get rep once a question is made CW, regardless of whether they're actually made CW or only new answers are).

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will. For example, I wouldn't have bothered to type and post any code in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763779/making-a-smooth-path-from-an-irregular-number-of-x-y-points-to-simulate-handwriti/1764958#1764958) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761768/action-script-3-code-design-question/1762497#1762497) had they been marked CW - would have just given links instead.

Answer (score 2):

CW's are not for regular questions where there is an answer, yes a CW will deter people away from your question, since it's answerable.

**Answer to the Edit**

Yes making a Question CW will make all answers in that question CW as well. Just see my answer as an example.

Comment: Surely you mean *not* answerable