# What, if anything, should we do when a question is marked CW inappropriately?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

There is a rep barrier to marking a question Community Wiki: the point being to [withold it from people who lack the experience to understand the purpose of CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/why-cant-i-mark-a-question-as-community-wiki-when-asking-it).  However it seems to me that perhaps the barrier is too low because a few times now I have come across questions which are clearly programming related and answerable but which have been marked as CW.  [Here is the latest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915226/persist-data-when-the-table-was-not-mapped-jpa-eclipselink), which triggered my question.

I know there is no way for the questioner or a random editor to reverse this, to prevent people toggling it to game the points system.  But having questions wrongly marked CW is bad because:

- it blurs the ownership of the question.  I have just edited the question I linked to (it had a shocking lack of punctuation) and now the identity of the OP is lost.
- the CW status might [discourage people from answering the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30492/will-making-my-question-community-wiki-kill-the-incentive-to-post-answers-for-it) because there's no rep to be gained.

So what, if any, action should we take?  If we flag it for Moderator Attention can they un-Wiki it?   Or is CW really a one-way street?

Comment: I think Diamond mods can Wiki and Unwiki posts.

Comment: I agree that blurring ownership of the question is bad when CW is used improperly.  But I would point out that it's by design for CW in general; that's part of the "Community" aspect of Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CW is a one-way street. There's no going back. Mods can make a question "fully" CW (i.e., convert the question and all existing non-CW answers to CW), but they cannot undo CW on any post.

---

I don't think the problem lies in the CW mechanism itself (aside from the implementation issues, which is a separate discussion) -- I think the problem is in educating users on *what CW really means*.

This is a particularly difficult thing to do because *there isn't one clear definition of **why** a post should be CW*. There are many different opinions on when CW should be used, or not used, so it's understandable that a new user won't be able to figure it out correctly all the time.

There is a long tooltip if you hover over the checkbox, but it only lists the *consequences* of CW, not the *conditions* under which that feature should be used.

[When to check the "community wiki" checkbox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26660/when-to-check-the-community-wiki-checkbox)